# MYSYS GIT LDAP authentication for windows

Tags: git

Where would I get the source code of MSYSGIT client. I want to implement LDAP authentication, recompile and use MSYSGIT client any help would be appreciated.

-Seba.

Comment: Does anyone else think that this project is blatantly misusing Google Code? The source should be easily available from the GC site - if he gits don't like that, they should host elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try here http://repo.or.cz/w/msysgit.git/

It would have been faster to type "mysysgit source" then to create a Stack Overflow account and type in this question.

Answer (score 0):

On [msysgit home](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/) there's a link to the [sources](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/wiki/msysGitSources?tm=4) with two git repos, [development environment](http://repo.or.cz/w/msysgit.git/) and [windows sources](http://repo.or.cz/w/git/mingw/4msysgit.git/).